# linux - forward ip packets between two hosts

Tags: linux, ip, routes, forward

I have 3 computers running CentOS: A, B, C. They have addresses 192.168.3.1, 192.168.3.2, 192.168.3.3. I cannot use a switch for this setup. B has two network cards connected to the others.

ie. A ----- B ----- C

A can ping B, and B can ping C. **How do I set it up such that A can ping C?**

On B, I've tried enabling IP forwarding using `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` as well as adding a route. But I haven't had luck. Could someone please help?

Thanks,
Fidel

Answer (score 1):

Because these three hosts are from the same network (192.168.3.) you can't just use normal routing scheme. In this case you need to setup *proxy arp*.

More on that: http://www.sjdjweis.com/linux/proxyarp/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try port forwarding.
Or if you use netcat, you can make B a server and A a client, have A send to B.  Then make C a server a B a client and then send the Packet from B to C. Something similar (but maybe not exactly) like this may work.

For A:

```
nc -u 192.168.3.2 portnumber
```

For B:

```
nc -l -u portnumber | nc -u 192.168.3.3 newportnumber
```

For C:

```
nc -l -u newportnumber
```

This way whatever you put into A, should be sent to C.  If you are working from a program, then you will not need the A and C stuff, just the server/client on B so that it can forward it.

Comment: Of course this solution will not work, because you need to have 192.168.3.2 in two separate networks at the same time. And if you have different networks on different interfaces you need no these tricks with netcat.